# Looking for an open-source terminal emulator written in modern C++

Tags: linux, open-source, c++, ubuntu, terminal-emulator

I often have to temporarily break my Python installation on Ubuntu in order to automate the configuration of `cmake` builds. Not a difficult break to fix, because I just replace the symlink in /usr/bin.

But anyway deleting this symlink out of being ignorant as to how to properly configure cmake with 10 different versions Python built from source, means breaking Gnome Terminal temporarily, which is my favourite term emulator.

I’m looking for a free ([open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source)) terminal emulator written in C++. I tried one written in Go and it just wasn’t fast or responsive enough.

Additionally, I’m not wanting to work with konsole, or Qt-based GUIs in general, so I’m wanting a C++ terminal emulator for Linux that writes directly to the framebuffer much like Xterm.

I'm aware that writing to the framebuffer in C++ is harder than writing to it in C. But what about OSes like Haiku? SHouldn't it have such a terminal emulator installed by default, since its kernel is almost pure C++ anyway?

Comment: "writes directly to the framebuffer" is not a modern architecture. So, demanding modern code, but a 1990's approach to displaying a terminal emulation is a bit contradictory.

Comment: "I often have to temporarily break my Python installation on Ubuntu in order to automate the configuration of cmake builds." That is … not right? You should not break system python to do anything for a build. This feels like the problem you need to solve, not any of the at least two layers of solutions-to-problems-that-you-should-actually-solve that you mention here. I mean, and please look at this from the humoristic side, "I need a modern C++ terminal emulator because of my CMake builds" is positively something that would make for good laughing material in a friendly round;it's a bit absurd.